# How can I change the push button colour when I select it and each layout i want to select one button only using pyqt4?

Tags: python, pyside

Here is my sample code. I have a horizontal and vertical row, and I will take my text in both horizontal and vertical. When I select the any button in layouts, that key button I want to change as blue colour when i choose the another button that button automatically update the blue colour and previous button will come in original colour
Given below is my code:

```
import sys
from PySide import QtGui,QtCore
from functools import partial
class Example(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()
    def initUI(self):
        self.hbox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.v1box = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.v2box = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.labl = QtGui.QLabel("horizontal")
        self.v1box.addWidget(self.labl)
        for key in ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']:
            self.btns1 = QtGui.QPushButton(str(key))
            self.btns1.clicked.connect(partial(self.text1, key, "horizontal"))
            self.v1box.addWidget(self.btns1)
        self.lab2 = QtGui.QLabel("vertical")
        self.v2box.addWidget(self.lab2)
        for key in ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']:
            self.btns2 = QtGui.QPushButton(str(key))
            self.btns2.clicked.connect(partial(self.text2, key,"Vertical"))
            self.v2box.addWidget(self.btns2)
        self.hbox.addLayout(self.v1box)
        self.hbox.addLayout(self.v2box)
        self.setLayout(self.hbox)
    def text1(self,key,type):
        if type == "horizontal":
            X = int(str(key))
            print X, "xxx"
    def text2(self,key,type):
        if type == "vertical":
            Y = int(str(key))

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: What do you mean by selecting? Do you mean to press?

Comment: yes when i press the any  button that button i want to show in blue colour

Comment: i knew to change the style sheet of the normal push buttons when i select it, but in this program  i am getting the text only, i not having any idea  to change the colour of the button when i select it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable the checkeable property of the QPushButton and use a QButtonGroup so that only one of them is checked. Then using the checked pseudo-state sets the desired style.

```
import sys
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui 
from functools import partial

class Example(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setStyleSheet("QPushButton::checked{ background-color:blue; border: none; }")
        v1box = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        v1box.addWidget(QtGui.QLabel("horizontal"))
        group1 = QtGui.QButtonGroup(self)
        for key in ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']:
            btn = QtGui.QPushButton(str(key), checkable=True)
            btn.clicked.connect(partial(self.text1, key, "horizontal"))
            v1box.addWidget(btn)
            group1.addButton(btn)

        v2box = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        v2box.addWidget(QtGui.QLabel("vertical"))
        group2 = QtGui.QButtonGroup(self)
        for key in ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']:
            btn = QtGui.QPushButton(str(key), checkable=True)
            btn.clicked.connect(partial(self.text2, key,"vertical"))
            v2box.addWidget(btn)
            group2.addButton(btn)

        hbox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self)
        hbox.addLayout(v1box)
        hbox.addLayout(v2box)

    def text1(self, key, direction):
        if direction == "horizontal":
            X = int(str(key))
            print(X, "xxx")

    def text2(self, key, direction):
        if direction == "vertical":
            Y = int(str(key))
            print(Y, "yyy")


def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: but sir in this program when i pressed the 2 number it will come in blue color again  i press the 6th number it is not updating both button are showing the blue color but i want to select the one number in each vertical layout

Comment: @raghava Explain better, point out that something does not work, but your question is basically: how to set a blue color when the button is pressed? and that's what my answer does, do you want that when you press it again it restores the initial color? Or do you want the color to be maintained while it is pressed and if the button is released, it must return to its initial color? Your question is not clear, explain yourself better.

Comment: @raghava Or do you want that in each column there is only one button with blue color ?, you realize that your question has many interpretations.

Comment: yes each column i want to show one button in blue colour when i select it, again i press the another button it will update and previous button will come in normal colour

Comment: @raghava Please edit your question and indicate that, also change the title of your question to something more appropriate.

Comment: I updatd my question sir